# How to create unique key for NavigationStateUtils using push route in React Native/Redux?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

Currently I have both Push and Pop set up using NavigationStateUtils using React Native/Redux. But when a button that triggers the Push action is pressed more than once, I get the error: `should not push * route with duplicated key` and * representing `route.key` or `this.props.navKey`.

What may be the cause of the error? How should I go about creating a unique key for each individual route using `NavigationStateUtils`?

This is my set up -
Redux:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    navigation: state.navReducer,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    pushRoute: (route) => push(route),
    popRoute: () => pop(),
  }
)(NavigationRoot)
```

My reducer (`navReducer.js`):

```
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   direction: 'horizontal',
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

And these methods handle push and pop and how navigation bar back (pop) button is set up:

```
  _renderScene (props) {
    const { route } = props.scene

    return (
      <route.component _handleNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)} {...route.passProps} actions={this.props}/>
    )
  }

  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

renderOverlay = (sceneProps) => {
if(0 < sceneProps.scene.index)
{
  return (
    <NavigationHeader
      {...sceneProps}
      renderLeftComponent={() => {
        switch(sceneProps.scene.route.title){
          case 'Home':
            return (
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handleBackAction()}>
                <Text}>X</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            )
          }
        }
      }
    />
  )
}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigationCardStack
          direction={this.props.navigation.routes[this.props.navigation.index].direction}
          navigationState={this.props.navigation}
          onNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)}
          renderScene={this._renderScene}
          renderOverlay={this.renderOverlay}
        />
    )
  }
```

And called by components like so:

```
const route = {
  home: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      direction: 'vertical',
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT console log**

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2 Continuation**

[image]

**EDIT 3 Slide Menu**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug your navigation reducer like this:

```
function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      console.log('action', action);
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
      const newNavigationState = NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route);
      console.log('newNavigationState', newNavigationState);
      return newNavigationState;

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Because of the way `NavigationStateUtils.push` works (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L60-L64)), it requires a completely new route to push to the route stack. Based on your navigation flow, you cannot use it again to go back home, you have to use a different function like [`NavigationStateUtils.pop`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L81-L92) or [`NavigationStateUtils.reset`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L186-L213) and others as well (explore that file). However, you are not limited to just the functions in `NavigationStateUtils`, you can define your own modification in the reducer but you need to make sure the navigation state has this data format:

```
{
  // `routes` needs to be an array of objects and each object
  // needs to have a unique `key` property
  routes: [{
    key: 'anything', // must be unique in this `routes` array
    ...anyOtherData
  }],
  // `index` is required, and has to be a number that refers 
  // to the index of the route in the routes array that is active
  index: 1,
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your requirements in your comments, every time your hit a drawer item, it needs to [reset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L186-L213) your navigation route stack having that route as your starting point, then you can start pushing and popping.

```
function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

    case DRAWER_ITEM_PRESS:
      // `action.route` is simply the route object of the drawer item you pressed
      return NavigationStateUtils.reset(state, [action.route], 0);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As another side note, I see that based on your requirements, it would probably be a good idea to try using [`react-native-router-flux`](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) because you will be able to define your [routes](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/DETAILED_EXAMPLE.md#detailed-example), [sub-routes](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#sub-scenes-support), [integrate with `react-native-drawer`](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#drawer-side-menu-integration) and [integrate with Redux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md#reduxflux).

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify on your question and show what you mean by `connect` function is not mapping `dispatch` with the code I provided?

Comment: How did you come up with:
`{
    pushRoute: (route) => push(route),
    popRoute: () => pop(),
  }`? from the `react-redux` documentation? It is supposed to be a function signature.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-2-implementing-redux-c6acbf66eca1#.trrcjkhju From here

Comment: Ah I see, so I think there's no issue there. However, I think the only way to find out what's going wrong is to debug the navigation reducer by logging what the new navigation `state` object after you've called `NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)`, and also see what the `action.route` object is. I updated the answer so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I did as you suggested and updated the original post with the screenshots of the console logs. Please take a look at both EDIT and EDIT 2. They are sequence of starting navigation from initial state of `Login` to `Home -> Shop -> Home`  And when I make that last push to `Home` that is when the error occurs.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but could you show an example with what you suggested integrated into my reducer for clarification? Also please take a looking at the original post with an image of Slide Menu that I am trying to implement for further clarification. Say you clicked on Notification button on the Slide Menu as shown in the image, then it would not have a hardware back button, and the same would go for Member button and so on for all the buttons on it. But say you click the Notification button, hide the Slide Menu and continue on the Notification page and navigate on it..

Comment: then the hardware back button would appear. When I navigate and continue within the same page, the push works perfectly fine with no error, but only the error occurs when triggered on the Slide Menu.

Comment: Checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know how if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I will give it a try but then with the new configuration, how should a component format the route based on the new change? For example, the original form was: `const route = {
  home: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      direction: 'vertical',
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Your form can stay the same you just need to add a new switch case to your `_handleNavigate` function.

Comment: Got it. So say for example the action call for it is called drawItemPress. In the switch case: it would just be `case: 'replace' return this.props.drawItemPress()` without any parameter?

Comment: The switch makes sense but you might need to pass an `action.route` into that `drawItemPress`, similar to your `push` switch case.

Comment: Didn't go well so decided to give react-native-router-flux but encountered a problem. Do you mind taking a look? I set it up with redux. Will accept answers for both. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609148/reactjs-redux-how-to-connect-mapdispatchtoprops-to-a-component